# Запятая перед "когда"

Tags: пунктуация

Требуется ли запятая между *только* и *когда*: *"Он разобрал надпись, только когда надел очки"?*

Answer (score 3):

**Если перед простым подчинительным союзом стоят усилительно-ограничительные слова (частицы, союзы или их сочетания, вводные слова) особенно, даже, в частности, в том числе, 
в особенности, а именно, а также, а (но) только, как раз, лишь, исключительно, только и др., то запятая ставится перед ними, а не перед союзом**: Неповторим Ярославль, ни с каким городом не спутаешь его, особенно когда увидишь город с Волги (М. Рапов); Хорошо в лесу весной, особенно когда (если) почки на деревьях только-только начинают раскрываться; Она обещала приехать, но только когда закончатся экзамены. ***(ПАС Лопатина)***

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, не нужна. Ставится одна запятая: перед придаточной частью.  Только - это усилительная частица.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, здесь вообще запятая не нужна.

Comment: Не, ну без запятой тут же два предложения без знака между ними получается. Или вы как-то по-другому эту фразу разбираете?

Comment: Почему два? Это одно предложение, имхо.    Разобрал надпись (сказуемое) (при каком условии?)    когда надел очки (обстоятельство). Только - усилительная частица.

Comment: Вот без "только" это однозначно сложное предложение. А в данном виде, мне кажется, его можно рассматривать как простое. Может, я не права.

Comment: "Он" - подлежащее, "разобрал" - сказуемое, "надел" - сказуемое, "когда" - подчинительный союз. Всё просто: [Он разобрал надпись], (только когда надел очки).

Comment: Для  behemothus. Не всегда запятая ставится непосредственно перед союзом или союзным словом.